# Как нарисовать снежинку с n лучей и n1 ярусов

Tags: c#

Есть фрагмент кода, он рисует что-то наподобии снежинки

```
public void snowflake(PaintEventArgs e,float x0,float y0,float xn,float yn,float r,int n,int n1)
        {
            Pen pen = new Pen(Pens.Black, 2);
            int i = 1;
            int i2 = 0;
            float xc = x + r;
            float yc = y + r;
            float ncur = 0;
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, x, y, 2 * r, 2 * r);
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, x - r, y - r, 4 * r, 4 * r);
            for (; i < n1 + 1; i++)
            {
                for (; i2 < n; i2++)
                {
                    float il = i2 - (n - 1) / 2;
                    //float rl = r / n1 * i;
                    ncur = n * (ncur + il);
                    xn = x0 + r * (float)Math.Cos((ncur + il) * 2 * (float)Math.PI / n);
                    yn = y0 + r * (float)Math.Sin((ncur + il) * 2 * (float)Math.PI / n);
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, xc, yc, xn, yn);
                }

            }

        }
```

Как сделать так, чтобы можно было выводить разное кол-во ярусов, по желанию? Сейчас всегда рисует только один ярус. X,y-координаты центра, r-радиус одного яруса

Есть также код на паскале, полностью рабочий

```
procedure drawsnowflake(x0, y0, x, y, r, n, k, kcur: integer; ncur, angle: real; color: system.drawing.color);
begin
  if kcur <= k then
  begin
    for var i := 0 to n - 1 do
    begin
      var i1 := i - (n - 1) / 2;
      var r1 := round(r / k * kcur);
      var x1 := round(x0 + r1 * cos((ncur + i1) * angle));
      var y1 := round(y0 + r1 * sin((ncur + i1) * angle));
      line(x, y, x1, y1, color);
      drawsnowflake(x0, y0, x1, y1, r, n, k, kcur + 1, n * (ncur + i1), angle / n, color);
    end; 
  end;
end;

var
  x, y, r, n, k, answer: integer;
  color: system.drawing.color;

begin
  while true do
  begin
    textout(0, 0, 'X = ');
    read(x);
    clearwindow;
    textout(0, 0, 'X = ');
    textout(25, 0, x);
    textout(0, 20, 'Y = ');
    read(y);
    textout(25, 20, y);
    textout(0, 40, 'R = ');
    read(r);
    textout(25, 40, r);
    textout(0, 60, 'Ветвлений = ');
    read(n);
    textout(80, 60, n);
    textout(0, 80, 'Ярусов = ');
    read(k);
    textout(60, 80, k);
    textout(0, 100, 'BorderColor = ');
    textout(0, 120, '0 - Black');
    textout(0, 140, '1 - Red');
    textout(0, 160, '2 - Green');
    textout(0, 180, '3 - Blue');
    textout(0, 200, '4 - Yellow');
    read(answer);
    fillrect(0, 120, 100, 220);
    case answer of
      1: begin color := clred; textout(90, 100, 'Red'); end;
      2: begin color := clgreen; textout(90, 100, 'Green'); end;
      3: begin color := clblue; textout(90, 100, 'Blue'); end;
      4: begin color := clyellow; textout(90, 100, 'Yellow'); end;
    else begin color := clblack; textout(90, 100, 'Black'); end;
    end;
    textout(25, 40, r);
    drawsnowflake(x, y, x, y, r, n, k, 1, 0, 2 * pi / n, color)
  end;
end.
```

Comment: А теперь представьте, что абсолютно все вопросы на StackOverflow будут иметь заголовок: "Всем привет. Срочно нужна помощь!". Как вы будете искать ответ на свои вопросы?

Comment: Понял, поменял тему.

Comment: Обратите внимание на строку `drawsnowflake(x0, y0, x1, y1, r, n, k, kcur + 1, n * (ncur + i1), angle / n, color);` в коде на паскале. Это называется "рекурсия". В коде на c# у вас её нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот мой вариант кода (назвал все аргументы по-человечески):

```
public static double ConvertDegreesToRadians(double degrees) =>
    Math.PI / 180 * degrees;

private void DrawSnowflake(Graphics graphics, Point center, Point localCenter, int radius,
    int forksCount, int layersCount, int layer, float forkIndex, float angle, Color color)
{
    for (int localForkIndex = 0; localForkIndex < forksCount; localForkIndex++)
    {
        var forksIndex1  = localForkIndex - (forksCount - 1) / 2;
        var radius1      = (int)((float)radius / layersCount * layer);
        var center1X     = (int)(center.X + radius1 * Math.Cos((forkIndex + forksIndex1) * angle));
        var center1Y     = (int)(center.Y + radius1 * Math.Sin((forkIndex + forksIndex1) * angle));
        var center1      = new Point(center1X, center1Y);

        graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(color), localCenter.X, localCenter.Y, center1.X, center1.Y);

        if (layer != layersCount)
        {
            DrawSnowflake(
                graphics:    graphics,
                center:      center,
                localCenter: center1,
                radius:      radius,
                forksCount:  forksCount,
                layersCount: layersCount,
                layer:       layer + 1,
                forkIndex:   forksCount * (forkIndex + forksIndex1),
                angle:       angle / forksCount,
                color:       color);
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Нарисовать снежинку
/// </summary>
/// <param name="graphics">Графика</param>
/// <param name="center">Центральная точка</param>
/// <param name="radius">Радиус</param>
/// <param name="forksCount">Количество ветвлений</param>
/// <param name="layersCount">Количество ярусов</param>
/// <param name="angle">Угол</param>
/// <param name="color">Цвет</param>
public void DrawSnowflake(Graphics graphics, Point center, int radius,
    int forksCount, int layersCount, float angle, Color color)
{
    if (layersCount <= 0)
        throw new Exception($"{nameof(layersCount)} <= 0");

    if (forksCount < 0)
        throw new Exception($"{nameof(forksCount)} < 0");

    DrawSnowflake(
        graphics:    graphics,
        center:      center,
        localCenter: center,
        radius:      radius,
        forksCount:  forksCount,
        layersCount: layersCount,
        layer:       1,
        forkIndex:   0,
        angle:       angle / forksCount,
        color:       color);
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    DrawSnowflake(
        graphics:    e.Graphics,
        center:      new Point(e.ClipRectangle.Width / 2, e.ClipRectangle.Height / 2),
        radius:      200,
        forksCount:  6,
        layersCount: 3,
        angle:       (float)ConvertDegreesToRadians(360),
        color:       Color.Black);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если убрать деление угла `angle / n` (python), `angle / forksCount` (c#), получится так:

```
if (layer != layersCount)
{
    DrawSnowflake(
        ...
        angle:       angle,// / forksCount,
        color:       color);
}
```

И картинка выйдет такая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD:**

Я посидел и переделал метод, так что бы он рисовал настоящую снежинку, вот что получилось:

```
private void DrawSnowflake(Graphics graphics, Point center, int radius, float radiusScale, int forksCount, int layersCount, int layer, float angle, Color color)
{
    for (int localForkIndex = 0; localForkIndex < forksCount; localForkIndex++)
    {
        var forkCenter = new Point(
            (int)(center.X + radius * Math.Cos(localForkIndex * angle)),
            (int)(center.Y + radius * Math.Sin(localForkIndex * angle)));

        graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(color), center.X, center.Y, forkCenter.X, forkCenter.Y);

        if (layer != layersCount)
        {
            DrawSnowflake(
                graphics:    graphics,
                center:      forkCenter,
                radius:      (int)(radius * radiusScale),
                radiusScale: radiusScale,
                forksCount:  forksCount,
                layersCount: layersCount,
                layer:       layer + 1,
                angle:       angle,
                color:       color);
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Нарисовать снежинку
/// </summary>
/// <param name="graphics">Графика</param>
/// <param name="center">Центральная точка</param>
/// <param name="radius">Радиус</param>
/// <param name="forksCount">Количество ветвлений</param>
/// <param name="layersCount">Количество ярусов</param>
/// <param name="angle">Угол</param>
/// <param name="color">Цвет</param>
public void DrawSnowflake(Graphics graphics, Point center, int radius, float radiusScale,
    int forksCount, int layersCount, float angle, Color color)
{
    if (layersCount <= 0)
        throw new Exception($"{nameof(layersCount)} <= 0");

    if (forksCount < 0)
        throw new Exception($"{nameof(forksCount)} < 0");

    DrawSnowflake(
        graphics:    graphics,
        center:      center,
        radius:      radius,
        radiusScale: radiusScale,
        forksCount:  forksCount,
        layersCount: layersCount,
        layer:       1,
        angle:       angle,
        color:       color);
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var forksCount = 6;

    DrawSnowflake(
        graphics:    e.Graphics,
        center:      new Point(e.ClipRectangle.Width / 2, e.ClipRectangle.Height / 2),
        radius:      150,
        radiusScale: 1f / 3,
        forksCount:  forksCount,
        layersCount: 5,
        angle:       (float)ConvertDegreesToRadians(360 / forksCount),
        color:       Color.Black);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Одуванчик))))))

Comment: @Andrew а метод называется снежинка  ‍♀️

Comment: Так надо пофиксить углы, и будет снежинка. Лучей то 6, просто углы между ними не те, должны быть 60 градасов.

Comment: @aepot так он внутри публичного `DrawSnowflake` на `forksCount` делится `angle:       angle / forksCount,` и получается `360 / 6 = 60`

Comment: Но на картинке же видно, что это не так :) угол между лучами 60 градусов и каждый следующий ярус должен быть короче предыдущего

Comment: @aepot поправил, стало и вправду похоже на снежинку, но я просто переписывал код с питона на шарп, так что не мой косяк)

Comment: Нене, эта картинка не похожа на фрактал снежинки. [Что-то типа этого](https://img2.freepng.ru/20180705/jxv/kisspng-fractal-dimension-n-flake-koch-snowflake-hausdorff-hexaflake-5b3df3b0235e16.3224777815307867361449.jpg) должно получиться, только там лучи в виде шестигранников, а у вас в виде линий должно получиться.

Comment: @aepot так тут алгоритм другой, он берёт рисует несколько лучей, потом в них ещё и так несколько раз

Comment: Ну, одуванчик больше похож на дело. Я просто про то, как может выглядеть фрактал-снежинка, [вот еще картинку нашел](https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJyq-VfUFeU97rG6qiGXOGF2A1CM4cF_cNWSVcP9ng=s900-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo).

Comment: @aepot теперь точно то

Comment: Вот теперь оно :) а с разным количеством лучей и уровней? Ну как в вопросе написано. :)

Comment: @aepot да, тут есть layer - это те самые ярусы

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за помощь, немного посидел и получилось это:

```
private void pic1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            draw(e, x+r, y+r ,x+r ,y+r , n, n1, 1, 0, (float)Math.PI*2/n);
        }
public void draw(PaintEventArgs e,float x0, float y0,float x, float y,float n,float n1,int n1cur,float ncur,float ang)
        {
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(br, bg, bb), 2);
            if (n1cur <= n1)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < n;i++)
                {
                    float i1 = i - (n - 1) / 2;
                    float r1 = r / n1 * n1cur;
                    float x1 = x0 + r1 * (float)Math.Cos(ang * (ncur + i1));
                    float y1 = y0 + r1 * (float)Math.Sin(ang * (ncur + i1));
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, x, y, x1, y1);
                    draw(e, x0, y0, x1, y1, n ,n1 ,n1cur + 1 ,n*(ncur + i1) ,ang / n);
                }
            }
        }
```

Вроде как работает, как и запланировано, оставлю это здесь, вдруг кому потом пригодится.